# Is beginTransaction() in hibernate necessary for one update/insert statement?

Tags: hibernate, session, transactions

I have only one update statement that I need to execute, do really need to begin a transaction for one statement?

Answer (score 0):

It could be. Although a single statement is already atomic by nature, If your database have trigger then transaction may become necessary.

Answer (score 0):

@Sahil Pimenta there are two ways 
1- for every operation of insert, update and delete you have to begin transaction in that code 
2- Manage transactions than use it :)